# Return a value in a range if a dropdown =

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to populate the adjacent cells in a sheet depending on the drop down box value.

In the workbook, I have a DATA sheet listing contact information, name, phone & email.

In the main sheet, you can select from the dropdown list a company name and then I would like to populate the adjacent cells with the information from the data sheet.

What would be the best method?

Cheers

Comment: Vlookup, Index/Match, Filter, Xlookup all these function will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Formula in `B3` I used-

```
=IF(A3="","",INDEX($I$3:$K$7,MATCH($A$3,$H$3:$H$7,0),COLUMN(A$1)))
```

With ***EXCEL-365*** you can use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(I3:K7,H3:H7=A3,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem with an event

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim strName As String
  Dim lngRow As Long, lngRowMax As Long
  Dim rngFind As Range


  If Target.Column = 1 Then

   lngRowMax = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   For lngRow = 2 To lngRowMax

    If Range("F" & lngRow).Value = Target.Value Then
     strName = strName & "," & Range("G" & lngRow).Value
    End If

   Next lngRow

   strName = Mid(strName, 2)


   Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation.Delete
   Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=strName

  End If

  If Target.Column = 2 Then
   Set rngFind = Range("G:G").Find(what:=Target.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
   If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
    Range("C" & Target.Row).Value = rngFind.Offset(0, 1).Value
   End If
  End If

End Sub
```

BG
Bernd